# How to express $\operatorname{adj}A$ as a linear combination of $A^{n-1}, A^{n-2}\dots A,I$. If $A$ is an $n×n$ non-singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> How to express $\operatorname{adj}A$ as a linear combination of $A^{n-1}, A^{n-2}\dots A,I$, if $A$ is an $n×n$ non-singular matrix?

I am not looking for a long proof or solution. However, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Perhaps the Cayley-Hamilton theorem will be useful here.

Comment: As a further hint, think about how you might expand $A^{-1}$ as a power series in $A$.

Comment: I know Cayley Hamilton theorem but I didn't understand how it will work. Could you help me to start ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is  starting point:

Let $p_A(t)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$.  By Cayley-Hamilton, $p_A(A)=0$.  Additionally, $adj(A)A=\det(A)I$.If $A$ is invertible, this lets you solve for $adj(A)$.

Comment: Thank you so much.